# How to get rid of the line on top of my button in a UIToolBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've created a `UIToolBar` and set two `UIBarButtonItem`s and then assigned this toolbar to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`.

Everything works perfectly except there is a line on top of my buttons.

The code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                           target:self
                                                           action:@selector(addNewRow:)];
UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                           target:self 
                                                           action:@selector(editRow:)];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
[toolBar setItems:@[addItem, editItem]];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolBar];
```

Please see my pic:
[image]

Comment: if you want to keep your uitoolbar then have you thought about hiding the status bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get rid of the line by getting rid of the toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addNewRow:)];
UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editRow:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[ addItem, editItem ];
```